# Count number of triangles

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

If we are given N lines and out of N lines M is the set of parallel lines and we are also provided M integers m1,m2,m3.. number of parallel lines in each set.

Here  2<=m1,m2,m3…<=N and m1+m2+m3..<=m

EXAMPLE : Let say we have N=7 AND M=2 and let number of parallel lines in each set be 2,2 respectively. Then here answer will be 9 triangles possible.

Comment: If you have seven lines with two pairs of two parallel lines and three others, there are ${7 \choose 3}-2\cdot 5=25$ triangles, because you can pick any set of lines except both of one pair and some other line.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  This is an inclusion-exclusion problem.  Any set of three lines will make a triangle unless it includes a pair of parallel lines.  If you just remove all the sets containing a pair of parallel lines, you will remove the sets containing three parallel lines three times.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: First imagine there is only one batch of parallel lines, so $m_1 \gt 1$, but all the other $m$'s are $1$.  You have $N \choose 3$ sets of three lines.  Each set will form a triangle unless at least two are parallel.  To get the number of sets with two lines parallel, you might do ${m_1 \choose 2}(N-1)$ where you choose a pair of parallel lines plus one more.  Can you see the overcount?

Comment: No..:(..could you please provide some formula for it

Comment: What do you understand about this?  Please be more explicit where the problem is.